# How big is largeheap in android

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory

Sorry if this has already been asked but I could not find it anywhere.

In android you have the annotation in the manifest file "Largeheap".
How much does does the heap actually increase when using it?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> android:largeHeap
> Whether your application's processes should be created with a large Dalvik heap. This applies to all processes created for the application. It only applies to the first application loaded into a process; if you're using a shared user ID to allow multiple applications to use a process, they all must use this option consistently or they will have unpredictable results.
> Most apps should not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall memory usage for improved performance. **Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.**
>
> To query the available memory size at runtime, use the methods
> getMemoryClass() or getLargeMemoryClass().

can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element